# How to host my react app made from vite into an API made by ocelot?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, vite, ocelot

I have made an API gateway using ocelot which runs on port 8000 and my react app runs on 3000 but when I am trying to redirect it using the API gateway I get error 404

I tried making a react app using create-react-app then just putting it in API gateway but it does not load.

Answer (score 0):

Try modify the PathTemplate of 404 resouce. (Browser F12-network to check)
You could try the following code.
ocelot.json

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ],
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 3000
        }
      ]
    }
  ],

  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "RequestIdKey": "OcRequestId",
    "AdministrationPath": "/administration"
  }
}
```

program.cs

```
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("ocelot.json");
builder.Services.AddOcelot(builder.Configuration);
...
await app.UseOcelot();
app.Run();
```

Test
[image]

Comment: It does work when I am running the npm run build and serving it as a static server. But when I am just running the development server such as npm start it doesn't load. Any reason on that